Having trouble accessing the values of an ElementTree root.iter object
I have an xml document from the IRS and I'm trying to grab the values of specific tags that interest me. For example, in the following xml data, I'm interested in the value of CYTotalExpensesAmt, which is 12345:
<returndata>
    <irs990>
        <CYTotalExpensesAmt>12345</CYTotalExpensesAmt>
    </irs990>
<returndata>

When I code the following, it returns a memory location:
x = root.iter('CYTotalExpensesAmt')
print(x)

But when I try to grab the value, the 12345, with the following code:
print(x.text)

or
for e in root.iter('CYTotalExpensesAmt'):
    print(e.text)

I get an error or nothing returned at all. Any ideas on what I can do differently to access the value of tags I know the name of but do not know their indexed location?

After fixing the final tag to be </returndata> instead of <returndata>, the root.iter() loop works as expected for me.  Can you please edit the question to show the full code and the exact error you're getting?

Also, tag the question with the XML library you're using.

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
Please edit your original question and provide the following:
(1) Well-formed XML file sample with all relevant namespaces.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic, and your code attempt trying to implement it.
(3) Desired output based on the sample data in #1 above.

Your first expression is an iterator and the text content can not entered directly. Change it to a list, e.g. :
(Note: The xml must valid, as commented by Gordon. If the root have a namespace definition, this must be considered extra, see comment from Khabinski)
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# close last tag as commented by Gordon
xml_ = """<returndata>
    <irs990>
        <CYTotalExpensesAmt>12345</CYTotalExpensesAmt>
    </irs990>
</returndata>"""

root = ET.fromstring(xml_)
# root = ET.parse(“your file.xml”).getroot()

# x is a iterator, you can change it to a list, take the first element and show the text)
x = root.iter('CYTotalExpensesAmt')
print(list(x)[0].text)

for elem in root.iter('CYTotalExpensesAmt'):
    print(elem.text)

Output:
12345
12345

If your xml use namespace like this example you can get the tag name:
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root=ET.parse('IRS990.xml').getroot()

for elem in root.iter():
    if "CYTotalExpensesAmt" in elem.tag:
        print(elem.tag)

E.g. Output something like:
{http://www.irs.gov/efile}CYTotalExpensesAmt

Than you can search the text:
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root=ET.parse('IRS990.xml').getroot()

for elem in root.iter("{http://www.irs.gov/efile}CYTotalExpensesAmt"):
    print(elem.text)


IRS XML documents are using namespaces. For example: <instrx xmlns="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:instr"         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"         xsi:schemaLocation="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:instr instrs.xsd"         format="2col" id="en_US_2024_publink10003818" language="english"         leadpct="0" list_type="flush" ptsize="10" setcolor="0">
